# How To Print Variable Data And String By Adding Inside Single Quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How To Output Variable data And String With Single Quotes.I Want To Add String After The Value Of mo.Output Should Be Inside  Single Quotes.
Output Should Be:-   '123target'

```
<button value="123" class="btn">Button 1</button>
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var mo = $(this).val();
   var re = '''+mo+'target'';
   document.write(re);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quote to wrap or escape it using `\`.

```
var re = '\'' + mo + 'target\'';
// or
var re = "'" + mo + "target'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var mo = $(this).val();
   var re = "'"+mo + "target'";
   document.write(re);
});
```

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3p2gb7p/1/) link.

You haven't kept quotes properly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var mo = $(this).val();
  var re = "'" + mo + "target'";
  document.write(re);
});
```

```html
<button value="123" class="btn">Button 1</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

additionally you can also use ES6 template strings (backtics)

```js
var mo = "quotes"
out.innerHTML=`some string in 'single ${mo}' and some in "double ${mo}" and also some "mix'd ${mo} content"`
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```